# Can you find a noun for the word "diminish"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What I meant by "diminish" is the reduction in value of something abstract.

For example:

> The purpose of the principle is to set a standard of morality
>   according to the promotion or __ of happiness among the individuals.

The blanks above should be filled with the noun of the verb "diminish".

Based on what I found on several sources on the internet, I found the noun: decrease & decline. But I cannot replace the blanks with "decrease" or "decline" because it seems to match in more concrete context such as numbers, graphs, etc. (If I don't sense it wrong).

Comment: If the sum of individuals in the society either promote happiness or diminish happiness, the standard of morality in that society will be valued according to both aspects..

Comment: Why can't you just use "reduction"?

Comment: It is not really intended to be increase and decrease. By diminish, I would like to mean to regard happiness as something less valuable.

Comment: @Al Everett As a foreigner, I sense "reduction" as something related to numbers, is that wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's not that exclusive. "Reduces swelling"--or, for your purposes, a "reduction in swelling"--is a perfectly reasonable statement and has nothing to do with numbers. It just means that something will be less swollen.

Comment: :/ Am I the only person who thought demotion?

Comment: *Deprecation* catches the intended sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use **diminution**. It's the noun form of the verb *diminish*.

Comment: Now I really can't tell the difference between diminution and diminishment. Why do you use diminution instead of diminishment?

Comment: _Diminution_ is much more common. You can see this [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diminution%2Cdiminishment&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3). You can also check [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=diminution&ls=a) where _diminution_ is found in lots of dictionaries. Finally, search Google for both terms separately and compare the number of results.

Comment: [This](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diminution%2Cdiminishment&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is the NGram showing the results between 2000 and 2008.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered "diminishing" in your sentence?

Answer (score 2):

The noun of diminish is diminishment.

eta: sorry, one noun form is as above.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are trying to create a semblance of a cadence in you writing, you could use **Demotion**